# How do i use tags in selenium tests using the Scala module for Playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've read the docs on tags for the normal templates:
[scala-0.9.1/templates#Tags](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/templates#Tags)

Now I'm trying to create a login-tag to be used in my selenium tests but I can't seem to get it to work.

In play for Java I have this:

```
# in file app/views/tags/test/loginAs.html
click('link=Log in')
type('css=.login input[name=email]', '${_email}')
type('css=.login input[name=password]', '${_password}')
clickAndWait('css=.login input[type=submit]')
```

In a test I use it like this:

```
#{test.loginAs email:'foo@bar.com', password:'1234' /}
```

Using Play with Scala I have tried this:

```
# in file app/views/tags/test/loginAs.scala.html
@(username:String, password: String)(body: (String) => Html)

click('link=Log in')
type('css=.login input[name=email]', '@email')
type('css=.login input[name=password]', '@password')
clickAndWait('css=.login input[type=submit]')
```

And in my test i first do the import:

```
import views.tags.html._
```

But when I call it from my test like so:

```
@loginAs("foo@bar.com", "1234")
```

I get no error, but no selenium code in my test either...

What I'm I doing wrong?

### Edit

So, it turns out you don't *have* to use the Scala templates... I tried to use the "normal" templates like the one I described above and It works fine.